# Mapping two one-to-many relationships into one collection in NHibernate

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'd like to map a `Person` object.

I've got the `People` table with `PersonId`, `FatherId` and `MotherId` fields (among others). The two last reference `PersonId` in the very same table.

In my domain model I'd like to have a `Children` read-only collection with every other `Person` having set their `FatherId` **or** `MotherId` to parent's `PersonId`.

One way to do that is to use two `HasMany` and map using `FatherId` and `MotherId` foreign keys respectively into `FathersChildren` and `MothersChildren` collections and returning one of those in a `Children` getter depending on the parent's gender. But that makes my domain object just ugly, so to speak.

Is there any way to solve this just in the mappings? I'd be happy with either fluent or hbm.

Comment: just an idea: you could map FatchersChildren and MothersChildren as virtual properties using an implementation of IGetter/ISetter to either *concate the lists* or *set the list depending on the gender*. this is some extra code you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was looking at my model and it came to me that **NHibernate** needs all properties to be `virtual` to allow **lazy-loading**. It returns an object with a class that inherits from the original. So I did the same.

My domain model stays the same:

```c#
public class Person
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual Gender Gender { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Person> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Entity class for mapping:

```c#
public class PersonEntity : Person
{
    public virtual IList<Person> FatherChildren { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Person> MotherChildren { get; set; }

    public override IEnumerable<Person> Children
    {
        get
        {
            return Gender == Domain.Gender.Male ? FatherChildren : MotherChildren;
        }
    }
}
```

And the mapping slightly modified for derived class:

```c#
public class PersonMap : ClassMap<PersonEntity>
{
    public PersonMap()
    {
        Table("People");

        Id(x => x.Id)
            .GeneratedBy.Guid();

        HasMany<PersonEntity>(x => x.FatherChildren)
            .KeyColumn("FatherId")
            .Inverse()
            .ReadOnly();

        HasMany<PersonEntity>(x => x.MotherChildren)
            .KeyColumn("MotherId")
            .Inverse()
            .ReadOnly();

        Map(x => x.Gender);
    }
}
```

Now I have a clean model!